# Specifying Oracle Service Name in UNIX Profile

Tags: oracle

Is there any way we can specify Oracle Service Name in UNIX Profile?

I know that there is an environment variable ORACLE_SID for specifying SID in the Profile,

But how about service name? If there is, then can we remove ORACLE_SID once we set the Service Name in the Profile?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?  The question doesn't make much sense to me.  In Linux-world, AIUI the SID is a combination of ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID which uniquely identifies a single database instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the TWO_TASK variable and set it to [server]/[service]

export TWO_TASK=server.example.com/mydb

This will override ORACLE_SID and make a sqlnet connection to the DB.

Comment: +1 Ask Tom: [What is TWO-TASK](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:89412348059)